# В Кейптаунском порту(,) с пробоиной в борту(,) «Жанетта» поправляла такелаж

Tags: запятые

Нужны запятые? Я думаю, что да. Это песня «В Кейптаунском порту».

> В Кейптаунском порту(,) с пробоиной в борту(,) «Жанетта» поправляла такелаж.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая нужна:

*В Кейптаунском порту, **с пробоиной в борту,** «Жанетта» поправляла такелаж.*

Это **уточняющая** информация, она не входит в **основное** сообщение. *Поправляла такелаж, **имея** при этом пробоину.*

Оборот не вписывается в предложение по всем **показателям** (семантика, грамматика, интонация). Это обособленное **несогласованное определение**, выраженное падежной формой существительного.